# incrementing Pool size with initial connections and max connections

Tags: java, postgresql, connection, pool

I'm doing a Pool app where there are 3 variables, A as initial connections which is 20, b as incrementing size meaning that when the pool reach 20, it will increment 5 by 5 the pool size, and y as the max connections that is 50, I'm having problems implementing the B variable in a conditional way, this is the code

```java
public class ThreadHolder extends Thread {
    ArrayList<Client> pool;
    public static int a = 20;
    public static int b = 5;
    public static int y = 50;
    public static long ftime, stime, time;
    public Client c = null;
    
    public ThreadHolder(){
        pool = new ArrayList<Client>();
    }
    
    public void run(){
        stime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            while(pool.size()<= y){     
                if(pool.size() < a){    
                    poolHelper();
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                }
                
                else if(pool.size()> a){
                    a = a+b;
                    poolHelper();
                    Thread.sleep(600);
                }   
                
                else {
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Database is busy, please try again in a second.");  
                    deleteClient(c);
                    System.out.println("Pool -> "+pool.size() + ".");
                    Thread.sleep(300);
            }   
                
            ftime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            time = (ftime - stime)/1000 ;
            System.out.println("Time established -> " + time + " sec");
            }   
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    
    public void poolHelper(){
        obtainClient(c);
        addClient(c);
        System.out.println("Pool -> "+pool.size() + ".");
    }
    
    public synchronized void obtainClient(Client c){
        Client a = new Client(this);
        a.start();
    }
    
    public synchronized void addClient(Client c){
        pool.add(c);
    }
    
    public synchronized void deleteClient(Client c){
        pool.remove(c);
    }
}
```

How can I implement the use of B, to keep adding clients to my pool when my poolsize reach more than 20 connections?